# Chrome is downloading HTML files instead of displaying them

Tags: html, iis, ftp

I need some help. I decided to create a home FTP server for my family. I hit a roadblock a few hours ago. When I was creating my home page, I wanted to test it in Chrome. I linked a css file to it aswell. I expected to see the test webpage, which was a h1 with the text hello. What actually happened was the fact that it downloaded my html file, and when I opened that in Chrome, I saw my page without the css. I've tried everything to speak of on this site and I even checked page 2 of Google. Here's my code, I'm running FTP on IIS 10.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, chrome download the html page is right. Since you use chrome to access a ftp file, it is not a http connection to the server. The chrome will not directly show it.

If you want to show the html page in the browser, you should use IIS website instead of ftp site.

More details about how to create a IIS web site, you could refer to below article.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/323972/how-to-set-up-your-first-iis-web-site

Answer (score -1):

i guess you are putting it in a wrong format 
as https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp says

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```